# I pulish my web project in vs 2013 ( web Forms with Individual User Accounts )

Tags: asp.net-identity

In VS 2013 I create  a web Forms  with Individual User Accounts and  I  use ASP.NET Identity  , my Login works and I change  as

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
 <forms LoginUrl="/Account/Login" defaultUrl="default.aspx" protection="All"></forms>
    </authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

(because if I use

`<loginUrl="/Account/Login" >`

my default page will be on first  page  and my login page is not my first page in my ie.)

When I host  my project in IIS ,the problem is that login is first page and it works at first, after I sign off and login it works correctly , but when I close ie and open the link again the login page  does not direct to default page .
User Name and Password is working because when I enter a incorrect one I get the "try again" message.
when I restart  the iis the login page  works and after I enter username  and password  and press login the default  page appears by closing the page the login page  does not direct to default page .

Answer (score 0):

your web.config file shows that you have revoke the access to pages for anonymous users by adding deny users="?" to it. This mean that every users that has not been authenticated yet, can not access to pages in that domain, and if they request to access any page in domain, he/she must be redirected to login page. 
I suggest you to put your protected pages in different folder, and add separate web.config file to that folder and config it's accessibility to users. and also put your public pages in different section and allow anonymous access to them